# Make button active if session variable matches

Tags: php, html

**Situation**

I have 3 buttons that are designed to be able to switch between different company's.

[image]

I have put those buttons in a form:

```
echo '<form action="?" method="post">';

foreach ($_SESSION['bedrijf'] as $value) { 
   echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="bedrijf_keuze[]" value="bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'"><img src="images/logo_'.$value.'_small.png" height="40"></button> '; 
} 
echo'</form>';
```

Thru POST I am using this as an session variable into the rest of the system:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    foreach($_POST["bedrijf_keuze"] as $key=>$value)
    {
        $bedrijf_keuze = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $value));
        $_SESSION['bedrijf_keuze'] = $bedrijf_keuze;
    }
}
```

Now when an button is clicked the form is send and when I echo I see the correct value of `$_SESSION['bedrijf_keuze']`

To be able to see which company is chosen I have replaced `class="btn btn-default"` with `if($_SESSION['bedrijf_keuze'] == "bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'") { echo 'class="btn btn-default active"'; } else { echo 'class="btn btn-default"'; }`

**Problem**

The button that is clicked and where the session value is set for is not shown as active.
The final code of the form is now:

```
echo '<form action="?" method="post">';

foreach ($_SESSION['bedrijf'] as $value) 
{ 
   echo '<button type="submit" '; 
   if($_SESSION['bedrijf_keuze'] == "bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'") { 
       echo 'class="btn btn-default active"'; } 
   else { 
       echo 'class="btn btn-default"'; 
   } 
   echo ' name="bedrijf_keuze[]" value="bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'"><img src="images/logo_'.$value.'_small.png" height="40"></button> '; 
} 
echo'</form>';
```

When I echo `$_SESSION['bedrijf_keuze']` and bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.' the values are corresponding. So what went wrong and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are comparing values that never can correspond.

`"bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'" != '"bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'"'`

<kbd>Code</kbd>

```
<?php
    $value = 'foo';

    echo "bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'";
    echo '"bedrijf_keuze_'.$value.'"';
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

```
bedrijf_keuze_'.foo.'
"bedrijf_keuze_foo"
```

Comment: OK, that waas the issue although I still don;t understand why this could be the issue.

Comment: be careful with [mixing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) double and single qoutes. The posted value of the button does not contain any single quotes, whereas your condition does because the double quotes arround it